# Going through a list of strings in C#?

Tags: c#, list, keyboard

I was wondering how would it be better to implement a system for browsing through a list of strings using the arrow keys? So far I have a populated list with a few test strings added to it like `foo`, `goo`, `hoo` and now I would like to have a textBox where I can browse through them using the up and down arrow keys.

Here is a bit of the code I have:

```
List<String> reload;

private void inputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
        int x = 0;
        reload.item(x);//this is my bogus guess on how it should be done
            try{
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
                    itemHandler();
                    inputBox.Clear();
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){
                    inputBox.Text = reload().item(x+1); //again bogus
                    x++;
                }

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)(
                    inputBox.Text = reload().item(x-1); //again bogus
                    x--;
                }

                else {}
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                rtbDisplay.AppendText("Error:" + ex );
            }
        }
```

Comment: can't you use dropdown or combobox for this?

Comment: I can do whatever I like but I want to learn how to work with lists as I had never used them before surprisingly...

Comment: `reload` is a bad object name

Comment: it is a placeholder name for SO more than anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` should be defined *outside* the method because you don't want it to be reinitialised to 0 every time the method is called.

If you are not familiar with lists I suggest you to read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) first.

Basically, you nearly got it:

```
int x = 0;
private void inputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){
    try{
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
            itemHandler();
            inputBox.Clear();
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){
            inputBox.Text = reload[x + 1];
            x++;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)(
            inputBox.Text = reload[x - 1];
            x--;
        }

        else {}
    }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            rtbDisplay.Text = "Error:" + ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you would need the indexing variable declared outside of the method, otherwise it will start with 0 each time. Second a List can be indexed using the `[ ]` operator

```
int index = 0;

private void inputBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter){
        itemHandler();
        inputBox.Clear();
    }

    // you should check here whether your index is between 0 and reload.Count-1
    if (reload.Count > 0 && index > 1 && index < reload.Count -1){

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up){
            x++;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)(
            x--;
        }

        inputBox.Text = reload[index]; 

    }    
}
```